# android: run timer for long period

Tags: android, timer

if i want to run a timer for a long time in android and show the user, when they go to a particular activity, for example, the duration since the timer started as a live number - how should I implement this? By live, i mean the time shown changes in real time as one would expect a timer to do. There will only need to be one instance of this timer, it'll pretty much be like android's stopwatch but implemented to function within a custom app.

Would I require wakelock?

should I create a service?

or should I just use a simple java timer?

any help/advice much appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean 'long timer' 1 minut, day?

You have to realise that android can kill you activity any time, so the activity is not the right place to do it.

You can run you operation in Service - his life is longer then activity's, but you probably want to check time even if user returns in activity after week or reboot device.

If you tell more info about what you want it'll be easier to solve you problem.

> show the user, when they go to a particular activity

As I see you problem the solution should be like this:

1. First enter to the activity - create timer, start it,
2. On activity stop save current value of the timer and system time,
3. On recreate activity read saved value and start new timer with value of init_value + (current_time - saved_time).

In this case you can be sure that timer is persistant even if user left your activity and even restart device.

And also battery life will be much more longer :)

Comment: The length of the timer would simply be until the user stopped it (it would be in their interest to stop it as the data it provides is for their benefit) but i'd say 8 hours maximum as a failsafe. With the method you mentioned, which sounds perfect, would I be able to show the user the elapsed time as a persistent notification or on the screen if they press the unlock key but dont actually unlock the screen?

Comment: You can show time for example in notification bar or wherever. Maybe the best way to do it to use Service and update message in notification from there - it's if you want to have 'fresh' data every second\minute. Don't rely on activi's logic when activity is gone.